# Disable searching on some fields in Elastic Search

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to enable searching in just one field "XYZ". I am using the follwing code but it's giving me error. Could you please help me with it?

```
{
  "dynamic": "false",
  "properties": {
    "ABC": {
      "type": "text",
      "index": false,
      "store": true
      
    },
    "PQR": {
      "type": "text",
       "index": false,
      "store": true
    },
    "XYZ": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. I want the fields "ABC" and "PQR" to be stored in elastic search but I also want to disable search on these fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [enabled mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html#enabled)

> The enabled setting, which can be applied only to the top-level
> mapping definition and to object fields, causes Elasticsearch to skip
> parsing of the contents of the field entirely. The JSON can still be
> retrieved from the _source field, but it is not searchable or stored
> in any other way:

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ABC": {
        "enabled":false
      },
      "PQR": {
        "enabled":false
      },
      "XYZ": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "ABC": "b",
    "PQR": "c",
    "XYZ": "a"
}
```

**Search Query:**
When searching on `PQR` field, there are no search results.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "PQR": {
        "query": "c"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 0,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "XYZ": {
        "query": "a"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64113718",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.13353139,
        "_source": {
          "ABC": "b",
          "PQR": "c",
          "XYZ": "a"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I want the fields "ABC" and "PQR" to be stored in elastic search but I also want to disable search from these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting below exception:

> "reason": "failed to create query: Cannot search on field [PQR] since
> it is not indexed.",

And its correct as in order to search it **needs to be indexed, which is controlled by index param which you have set as false**.

Your current setup is correct and you need to exclude fields from your search queries which are not indexed and its a very common pattern followed by a lot of applications, otherwise, you can follow the Bhavya's answer but there these fields will be stored as part of `_source` and make sure it's not disabled(it's enabled by default).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not using the syntax correctly :

```
PUT indexName
{
  "mappings": { // <=============== This is missing
    "dynamic": false,
    "properties": {
      "ABC": {
        "type": "text", //<============= If type is object, use 'enabled' instead of 'index' 
        "index": false, 
        "store": true
      },
      "PQR": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": false,
        "store": true
      },
      "XYZ": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**

1. enabled = false is generally used with fields of type object
2. index = false is used with predefined types like text, etc
3. Both index=false & enabled=false will make the field non-indexable but the field will still be there in the _source.
4. For the fields where index=false, any search requests on those fields will result in the following error :

   ```
    Cannot search on-field [xyz] since it is not indexed
   ```
5. For any fields (type=object) where enabled = false, any search requests on those fields wouldn't result in any error.